# parameter mismatch,pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Tags: laravel

Trying to resend login details to a user through his mail.what I want to do is after the user has click on the forgotten password link, a form is displayed requesting for his email to be posted.after the email has been posted, I check if the email corresponds to an email in the users table and send details.

Here's my controller:

```
public function postResendPassword()
{
    $posted = Input::get();

    $email = $posted['email'];

    $user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();

    $user_password= $user->password_confirmation;

    $user_username = $user->username;
    $user_email = $user->email;


    $to =  $user->email;

    $subject = " login details request";

    $message = 

    <h3>login details</h3>
    email : $user_email
    login password : $user_password

    regards;

    mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
```

how do I go about this and fix this error

Comment: I don't know if you had a copy/paste issue, but your message is missing quotes surrounding its content. And if you are able to send your user's password to them in plain text, you're doing something WRONG.

Comment: I really suggest that you read this http://laravel.com/docs/security#password-reminders-and-reset. Laravel already takes care of this for you.